# Unable to replicate : "Comparison method violates its general contract!"

Tags: java, sorting, exception, compare, comparator

I receive the following error: "Comparison method violates its general contract!" when using the following comparator, however I am unable to replicate the exception using jUnit. I'd like to know what caused this issue and how to replicate it. There are examples of others having the same problem but not how to replicate it.

```
public class DtoComparator implements Comparator<Dto> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Dto r1, Dto r2) {

        int value = 0;

        value = r1.getOrder() - r2.getOrder();

        if (value == 0 && !isValueNull(r1.getDate(), r2.getDate()))
            value = r1.getDate().compareTo(r2.getDate());

        return value;
    }

    private boolean isValueNull(Date date, Date date2) {
        return date == null || date2 == null;
    }
}
```

The code is called by using:

```
Collections.sort(dtos, new DtoComparator());
```

Thanks for any help.

Extra info:
The error seemed to occur in the TimSort class inside Java utils and from within a method called mergeLo.
Link: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TimSort.java#TimSort.mergeLo%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: Do you have any very large orders (positive or negative)?

Comment: Hi immibis, The orders range from 1-20

Comment: The question why it fails for lists with length >= 32 was just now answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29866539/1639625)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of `compare`.

> The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`

Subtraction-based comparators do not meet this condition. This is because the subtraction can overflow. For example

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE - 0
0 - Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

are both negative.

There is also a problem with the way you have dealt with `Date`s. From the documentation of `compare`:

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

Your `compare` method breaks this. For example, if `x` is `null`, `y` is January 1st 1970 and `z` is January 2nd 1970, then

```
compare(x, y) == 0  // x == null
compare(x, z) == 0  // x == null
compare(y, z) == -1 // January 1st is before January 2nd.
```

I would write the method as follows:

```
@Override
public int compare(Dto r1, Dto r2) {

    int value = Integer.compare(r1.getOrder(), r2.getOrder());
    if (value != 0)
        return value;
    Date date1 = r1.getDate();
    Date date2 = r2.getDate();
    if (date1 == null && date2 == null)
        return 0;
    if (date1 == null)
        return -1;
    if (date2 == null)
        return 1;
    return date1.compareTo(date2);
}
```

I have managed to reproduce the problem, but only for `List`s of length at least `32`. See this link for an explanation of why a `List` of size at least `32` is required. [Why does this program using Collections.sort only fail for lists of size 32 or more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866539/why-does-this-program-using-collections-sort-only-fail-for-lists-of-size-32-or-m)

```
public class Main {

    private static final class NumAndDate {
        private final int num;
        private final Date date;

        NumAndDate(int num, Date date) {
            this.num = num;
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public static final class NumAndDateComparator implements Comparator<NumAndDate> {

        @Override
        public int compare(NumAndDate r1, NumAndDate r2) {

            int value = 0;

            value = r1.num - r2.num;

            if (value == 0 && !isValueNull(r1.date, r2.date))
                value = r1.date.compareTo(r2.date);

            return value;
        }

        private boolean isValueNull(Date date, Date date2) {
            return date == null || date2 == null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumAndDate[] array = {
                new NumAndDate(0, new Date(0)),
                new NumAndDate(0, new Date(1)), 
                new NumAndDate(0, null)
        };
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                List<NumAndDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
                int[] arr = new int[i];
                for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    int rand = random.nextInt(3);
                    arr[k] = rand;
                    list.add(array[rand]);
                }
                try {
                    Collections.sort(list, new NumAndDateComparator());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(arr.length + " " + Arrays.toString(arr));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, any idea how I would replicate the issue in a test? I have created a large list with some dates being null but the tests seem to always work fine.

Comment: @PhilHarper I'll have a think about it. I may be a while as before reading your question I didn't know `Collections.sort()` could throw this exception. I always assumed that is would silently produce a meaningless result if the comparator was broken.

Comment: @PhilHarper I've written  a program to reproduce the problem. See my updated answer.