# Why does this program using Collections.sort only fail for lists of size 32 or more?

Tags: java, collections

The following program throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I understand the problem with the `Comparator`. See [Unable to replicate : "Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865439/unable-to-replicate-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

I don't understand why it only fails for `List`s of size 32 or more. Can anyone explain?

```
class Experiment {

    private static final class MyInteger {
        private final Integer num;

        MyInteger(Integer num) {
            this.num = num;
        }
    }

    private static final Comparator<MyInteger> COMPARATOR = (r1, r2) -> {
        if (r1.num == null || r2.num == null)
            return 0;
        return Integer.compare(r1.num, r2.num);
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInteger[] array = {new MyInteger(0), new MyInteger(1), new MyInteger(null)};
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int length = 0;; length++) {
            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 100000; attempt++) {
                List<MyInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();
                int[] arr = new int[length];
                for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
                    int rand = random.nextInt(3);
                    arr[k] = rand;
                    list.add(array[rand]);
                }
                try {
                    Collections.sort(list, COMPARATOR);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(arr.length + " " + Arrays.toString(arr));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can reproduce. It seems to always fail at length 32. Probably some obscure implementation detail of the sorting algorithm... Or maybe starting at length 32 a different algorithm is used?

Comment: @tobias_k I'm just curious to know what that implementation detail is. Obviously the 3 downvoters aren't!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, but in [openjdk 8](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TimSort.java/?v=source) the size of the array is checked against MIN_MERGE, which is equal to 32. This avoids the call to `mergeLo`/`mergeHi` which throw the exception.

> From [JDK / jdk / openjdk /  7u40-b43 8-b132  7-b147 - 8-b132 
>   / java.util.TimSort](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TimSort.java/):
>
> ```
> static <T> void sort(T[] a, int lo, int hi, Comparator<? super T> c,
>                      T[] work, int workBase, int workLen) {
>     assert c != null && a != null && lo >= 0 && lo <= hi && hi <= a.length;
>
>     int nRemaining  = hi - lo;
>     if (nRemaining < 2)
>         return;  // Arrays of size 0 and 1 are always sorted
>
>     // If array is small, do a "mini-TimSort" with no merges
>     if (nRemaining < MIN_MERGE) {
>         int initRunLen = countRunAndMakeAscending(a, lo, hi, c);
>         binarySort(a, lo, hi, lo + initRunLen, c);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * March over the array once, left to right, finding natural runs,
>      * extending short natural runs to minRun elements, and merging runs
>      * to maintain stack invariant.
>      */
>     TimSort<T> ts = new TimSort<>(a, c, work, workBase, workLen);
>     int minRun = minRunLength(nRemaining);
>     do {
>         // Identify next run
>         int runLen = countRunAndMakeAscending(a, lo, hi, c);
>
>         // If run is short, extend to min(minRun, nRemaining)
>         if (runLen < minRun) {
>             int force = nRemaining <= minRun ? nRemaining : minRun;
>             binarySort(a, lo, lo + force, lo + runLen, c);
>             runLen = force;
>         }
>
>         // Push run onto pending-run stack, and maybe merge
>         ts.pushRun(lo, runLen);
>         ts.mergeCollapse();
>
>         // Advance to find next run
>         lo += runLen;
>         nRemaining -= runLen;
>     } while (nRemaining != 0);
>
>     // Merge all remaining runs to complete sort
>     assert lo == hi;
>     ts.mergeForceCollapse();
>     assert ts.stackSize == 1;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Java 8 uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm to sort the input. In `TimSort` there is a merging phase that happens when the length is at least 32. When the length is lower than 32 then a simple sorting algorithm is used that probably doesn't detect the contract violation. Let the source code comments of `TimSort.java` speak for itself:

```
class TimSort<T> {
    /**
     * This is the minimum sized sequence that will be merged.  Shorter
     * sequences will be lengthened by calling binarySort.  If the entire
     * array is less than this length, no merges will be performed.
     *
     * This constant should be a power of two.  It was 64 in Tim Peter's C
     * implementation, but 32 was empirically determined to work better in
     * this implementation.  In the unlikely event that you set this constant
     * to be a number that's not a power of two, you'll need to change the
     * {@link #minRunLength} computation.
     *
     * If you decrease this constant, you must change the stackLen
     * computation in the TimSort constructor, or you risk an
     * ArrayOutOfBounds exception.  See listsort.txt for a discussion
     * of the minimum stack length required as a function of the length
     * of the array being sorted and the minimum merge sequence length.
     */
    private static final int MIN_MERGE = 32;
```