# Sorting an array in java with certain conditions

Tags: java

I have a class called Athlete which is a sublass of Human. In the class Human I implement the interface comparable and use the method compareTo in order to compare the ages of different athletes. In the athletes class I have an extra field called year which corresponds to the year the athlete started competing. In my main method in my program I have an arraylist that I add both Athletes and Humans. I would like to so that if an athlete is of the same age to sort according to the year the athlete started competing. I use instanceof to check in my class human if the instance is the object is of type Athlete but after that I don't know how to get it to work.

```
    public int compareTo(Human other)
    {

        if(this instanceof Athlete && other instanceof Athlete && this.age == other.age){
            return ;
        }
        return this.age - other.age;
    }
}
```

Comment: What to do when an Athlete and a Human, which is not an Athlete, are compared with each other? Athletes first/last? non-Athlete-Humans first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a `compareTo` method in the `Athlete` class also, something in the lines of (needs rewriting as I haven't been working on Java since a long time ago):

```
public int compareTo(Athlete other){
    int result = super.compareTo((Human)other);

    if(result == 0){
        return this.year - other.year;
    }

    return result;
}
```

As a code review, I'd say that the complete code should be something like the following:

**Human.java**

```
public int compareTo(Human other){
    return age - other.age;
}
```

**Athlete.java**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Human other){
    if(other instanceof Athlete){
        return compareTo((Athlete)other);
    }

    return super.compareTo(other);
}

public int compareTo(Athlete other){
    int result = super.compareTo((Human)other);

    if(result == 0){
        return this.year - other.year;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't override a method and change the type of the argument.

Comment: @PaulBoddington you're right, that's not overriding in this case, my bad. I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), instead of the operator `instanceof`.

That is: overload the compareTo method in the Athlete class.

```
public int compareTo(Athlete other) {
//This method will be invoked if and only if you compare an athlete with another athlete
}
```

Also, consider that the equals method result should be consistent with the compareTo method results.

Comment: How? It is possible, but it's very complicated in this case.

Comment: The trouble is that compareTo in the athlete class must accept a Human argument. So you either need to use instanceof anyway or do something like `return -human.compareToAthlete(this);`, where `compareToHuman` is a completely separate method with 2 versions. Is this worth it?

Comment: It must not accept a Human argument. To compare an Athlete with a Human, you use the Human version of compareTo.

Comment: You can't override compareTo and change the tupe of the argument. It has to be Human. You don't decide which method to use anyway. If you do a.compareTo(h) where a is an Athlete and h is a human, it's the version in Athlete that gets used, and the argument is a Human.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Have you ever overriden equals(Object other)?

Comment: Yes. And I always write equals(Object o). I never write equals(OtherClass o) because you can't change that.

Comment: You can do it. However, I agree that strictly speaking, you're overloading the method and not overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you could just compare the year as well:

```
public int compareTo(Human other)
{

    if(this instanceof Athlete && other instanceof Athlete && this.age == other.age){
        String tYear = ((Athlete)this).getYear();
        String oYear = ((Athlete)other).getYear();
        int tYearInt = 0;
        int oYearInt = 0;
        try {
           tYearInt = Integer.parseInt(tYear);
           oYearInt = Integer.parseInt(oYear);
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  tYearInt - oYearInt;
    }
    return this.age - other.age;
}
```

However, having said that, please consider @Andres answer, anytime you use instanceof, you should question whether your design is wrong.

Comment: .getYear returns a string and when I want to return an int. When I go to use Integer.parseInt((Athlete)this).getYear()) I get an error saying: an int cannot be applied to Human.Athlete. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Like Andres said, use polymorphism. Here is how to do that:

First of all, `this instanceof Athlete` in the `Human` class is not good style, because from the perspective of the `Human` class, `Athlete` is a subclass and referencing subclasses can lead to problems in certain cases. Instead, put another `compareTo()` method into the `Athlete` class. If `Athlete.compareTo()` gets called, you already know that `this` is of type `Athlete` and if you want to compare the `year` field, you only have to check if `other instanceof Athlete`, which is ok, because now we are in the perspective of the `Athlete` class and from here, `Athlete` is not a subclass.

That said, in the `Athlete` class, use this:

```
public int compareTo(Human other) {
    int humanComp = super.compareTo(other);
    if (humanComp != 0){
        return humanComp;
    }

    if (other instanceof Athlete) {
        return ((Athlete)other).year - this.year;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This solution first uses `Human.compareTo()` (called with `super.compareTo(other)`) to check if the `Human` class already knows how to order our instances `this` and `other`. If not, i.e. if this call returns 0, we have to go on with comparing more details, in our case the `year` field.
Because we used `Human.compareTo()`, we have to make sure it exists in the `Human` class and that it works properly:

```
public int compareTo(Human other) {
    return this.age - other.age;
}
```

This one simply compares by `age`, because that's the only field in the `Human` class we know we can use for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for `compareTo` says:

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

Your proposed method does not meet this requirement. For example, suppose

```
x = Athlete, age = 35, start date = 2000
y = Human,   age = 35
z = Athlete, age = 35, start date = 2001
```

In this example

```
x.compareTo(y) == 0   // y is not an athlete
x.compareTo(z) < 0    // Both athletes, different start dates.
y.compareTo(z) == 0   // y is not an athlete
```

If you do not obey the contract for `Comparable`, the behaviour of `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` is unspecified. Ideally you'd get an exception, but the trouble is these sorting methods use different algorithms depending on the size of the array or list, and you are [more likely to get an exception thrown for an incorrect `compareTo` method if the input array or list has a large number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866539/why-does-this-program-using-collections-sort-only-fail-for-lists-of-size-32-or-m). This means that you should test your `compareTo` method very carefully using long randomly generated arrays, otherwise you may have subtle, hard-to-detect bugs in your code.

A correct `compareTo` method looks something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Human other) {
    int result = Integer.compare(age, other.age);
    if (result != 0)
        return result;
    if (!(this instanceof Athlete))
        return other instanceof Athlete ? -1 : 0;
    return other instanceof Athlete 
               ? Long.compare(((Athlete) this).startDate(), ((Athlete) other).startDate()) 
               : 1;
}
```

This method sorts first by age. If two humans have the same age they are sorted first by type (with athletes coming first). Athletes with the same age are sorted by start date. Non-athletes with the same age do not appear in any particular order.

Finally, note that it is generally better to use polymorphism rather than `instanceof`. The problem here is that `Human implements Comparable<Human>`. Therefore the `compareTo` method must accept a `Human`, not an `Athlete`. Even if you override `compareTo` in `Athlete`, the argument must be a `Human`, and you'd have to use `instanceof` to check the type of the argument anyway (as in @GentianKasa's answer) **or** write a completely separate method `compareToAthlete(Athlete athlete)` and do the following in `Athlete`

```
@Override 
public int compareTo(Human human) {
    return -human.compareToAthlete(this);  // Note the minus sign!
}
```

`compareToAthlete` would need two versions as well. While this works, it means that the logic of the `compareTo` method is spread over four methods, making it harder to reason about its correctness. In this case, I'd hold my nose and use `instanceof`.