# TreeSet not being ordered by custom Comparator as expected

Tags: java, groovy, comparator, treeset

I have a TreeSet which is populated with classes. I want to have these ordered by their inheritence otherwise, just by their name alphabetically (to create a constant order). But for some reason, if the order of the classes being added isn't correct, it causes the classes to be not be ordered properly.

Here is my Comparator:

```
class OrderedComparator implements Comparator<Class<?>> {

    @Override
    int compare(Class<?> clazz1, Class<?> clazz2) {
        if (clazz1 == clazz2) {
            return 0
        } else if (clazz1.isAssignableFrom(clazz2)) {
            return -1
        } else if (clazz2.isAssignableFrom(clazz1)) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return clazz1.canonicalName.compareTo(clazz2.canonicalName)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example failing test:

```
def 'OrderedSet is ordered in inheritence order, classes added multiple times'() {
    setup:
    Set<Class<?>> orderedSet = new TreeSet<>(new OrderedComparator())
    when:
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    orderedSet.add(com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class)
    then:
    assert orderedSet[0] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[1] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[2] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[3] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[4] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[5] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[6] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class
    assert orderedSet[7] == com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation.class
}
```

Actual value of orderedSet:

```
0 = {Class@1272} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
1 = {Class@1474} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
2 = {Class@1475} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
3 = {Class@1271} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
4 = {Class@1480} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
5 = {Class@1286} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
6 = {Class@1287} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
7 = {Class@1476} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
```

My expectation would be something more like:

```
0 = {Class@1271} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
1 = {Class@1272} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
2 = {Class@1474} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
3 = {Class@1475} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.jaxrs.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
4 = {Class@1286} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
5 = {Class@1287} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithClassAnnotation"
6 = {Class@1476} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.TestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
7 = {Class@1480} "class com.benjaminsproule.swagger.gradleplugin.test.springmvc.ExtendedTestResourceWithoutClassAnnotation"
```

I did notice when debugging, that not every item is compared with each other.

Comment: `"...not every item is compared with each other"` -- nor should it if the sorting is done efficiently

Comment: Sorting is done in [`O(n*lg(n))`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques) at best. Comparing every item is done in `O(n^2)` time. This is why a `Comparator` must conform to [the contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: Thanks @boristhespider, I was assuming there was something like that going on. Clearly not thinking straight today!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider these classes

```
class A extends C {}

class B {}

class C {}
```

Here `A` comes before `B` (neither is a subclass of the other, so order alphabetically).

Similarly `B` comes before `C`.

If your `Comparator` were transitive it would mean `A` came before `C`. However,

```
compare(A.class, C.class) == 1   // Because A is a subclass of C
```

meaning that `A` is "greater than" `C`.

As soon as you start trying to order using invalid comparators, the behaviour is not specified.

Comment: That's the one. If the `Comparator` doesn't conform to the specified contract, then you get UB. I find it marginally surprising that it doesn't just blow up - since they added TimSort there are more strict checks on the correctness.

Comment: @BorisTheSpider I asked about this a while ago. I think it can only blow up if the size of the list is at least 32 (?). I'll see if I can find the link.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/29866539/3973077. For size >=32 a different algorithm is used.

Comment: I came to the conclusion I was being stupid and ended up taking a different approach, but wanted clarification that I was an idiot.

Comment: @gigaSproule You definitely were not being an idiot. That comparator does look correct at first glance and it took me a long time to figure out why it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Try to change condition:

```
if (clazz1 == clazz2) {
    return 0;
} else if (clazz1.isAssignableFrom(clazz2)) {
    return 1; // this changed
} else if (clazz2.isAssignableFrom(clazz1)) {
    return -1; // this changed
} else {
    return clazz1.getCanonicalName().compareTo(clazz2.getCanonicalName());
}
```

Because I see inversion in Test* and ExtendedTest* classes between your expectations and actual ordering.